# Bitbucket Pull Request where source repo is forkee and destination repo is fork

Tags: git, bitbucket

A few months ago, I forked a repo called `alpha` and called the fork `beta`.

All I really wanted to acheive was a copy of the repo with the commit history preserved and a link to where it came from. The changes being made to `beta` were never inteded to be merged back into `alpha`; development on `alpha` had come to an end.

In a twist of fate, I needed to test out a feature (new image sensor, this is a firmware project) and to cut a long story short, it was not possible to test these hardware changes using the `beta` repo (microprocessor has changed from `alpha` to `beta`). So I branched on `alpha` to write code for the new feature.

Now, I want to pull the changes made on the feature branch in `alpha` (that which was forked) into the master branch of `beta` (the fork). This is the opposite way round to which Pull Requests are intened to be used, I know. In the Bitbucket UI I cannot specify `beta` as the destination repo when creating a pull request in `alpha`. As expected, however, I can create a pull request in `beta` with a destination of `alpha`.

I really don't want to resort to copying and pasting the code across on my local copies of the two repos because I would lose the commit history of the feature branch in `alpha`. Is there a way (using pull requests or otherwise) to pull code from `alpha` into `beta` and perform a merge commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here's how I did it:

`cd beta
git remote add my_new_remote https://me@bitbucket.org/.../alpha.git
git fetch my_new_remote branch_I_want
git branch -a`

Now we see `remotes/my_new_remote/branch_I_want` in the branches known to my local git repo.

Next, we need to make a local branch to track this newly added remote branch:

`git checkout -b my_local_branch my_new_remote/branch_I_want`

Now I've got a copy of the `branch_I_want` from the remote of `alpha` in my local copy of `beta`. So from here I can merge `my_local_branch` into `master` and push to `origin_mater` of `beta`.

Merging went like this:

`git checkout master
git merge my_local_branch`

Then fix the merge confilicts and `git commit`.

Finish off with a `git push` and now check bitbucket: all the commit history from `branch_I_want` in `alpha` is now in `beta`'s and the merge shows up just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Your `beta` repo is fork, and `alpha` - is `upstream` repo for it. Thus, if you've **branched** from `alpha` (means - created branch, not fork - am I right?), then you need to merge changes to `alpha` (via pull request, or simple merge); and then synchronize your fork `beta`, and upstream repository (`alpha`).

Check this link - https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/keeping-forks-synchronized-776639961.html - there are described some manual strategies for it.

At the end it means, that you need to merge `alpha` into `beta` - and this is normal routine while working via forks. Because meanwhile one works on the feature on his fork, other developers implement features and pull requests to upstream repository - and then, all of them could synchronize it.